# How to paint the wall with gradient patterns?

Tags: painting

I want to paint the wall of my bedroom like below. I have enough painting skills to paint the whole house, straight. So I believe I can pull this out. But I wanted check about the methods.

- For the color tones, can I use those 2 edge colors(dark blue & beige), and white to tone them, and to give the gradient look for each layer?
- What are those colors?
- What kind of tools I need? A regular brush for all of it? Or brush for the 
  edges, and a roller for the insides?
- What kind of paint I need? Wall paint? or should I use some kind of
  oil paint?  Acrylic or watercolor?
- Is this doable for an amateur?

[image]

Comment: I would recommend practicing on some sheets of drywall before attempting the final result on your actual wall.

We have been getting sample sized paint colors and painting scrap pieces of drywall to get a better idea of the colors we want.

Good luck!

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions. Any advice on this matter would be appreciated :)

Comment: Hi Tolga,

To get the pattern right, you could projector it onto the wall and then trace lightly with a pencil. After that, it would be a matter of freehand paining the edges.  This video is for more complicated work, but the concept should be clear https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=z7aGj8SMmHI

Also, I would recommend starting with the base colour (whatever the 'back' mountain is) and paint the whole wall.  Then build it up painting the closer/darker mountains one at a time. If you're using painters tape, remember not to leave it on too long. Also go the blue delicate stuff.

Comment: The work is by [Pam Lostracco](http://www.pamlostracco.com/) who lives in Toronto.  Maybe you could ask her...

Comment: Pick out the colors via paint swatches at the store. Buy wall paint. Use a brush.

Comment: DA01 and wallyk you guys are plagiarizing my answer, though no harm no foul!

Answer (score 4):

A quart typically covers ~ 100 sqft.  A pint or 8oz per color ought to do it.  Pints at a big box store are less than $5, and one store seems to have a 50% sale on these sizes.

To find works by other people, Google image search for: mountain wall mural layered. In comparing them, try to identify particular aspects of the ones you like that make them work so well.  Also, relative to those murals, take into account your flooring color, furniture colors etc.  This will aid in assessing whether to 'tint with white' or get the store to mix each tint.

Print out a color image of mural of your choice (maybe take the URLs to Kinkos or Staples or a photo store and ask them to print it to 'match'), take the print to the paint store, find color swatches that match.

Here is a blog post that describes the tinting:

http://www.trailtosummit.com/create-a-mountain-mural/

Here are very detailed step instructions, including wine and including a photo showing all their paint chips with codes:

http://kristinatravels.blogspot.com/2016/06/how-to-paint-mountain-mural.html

Your person wrote a blog post about her process:

http://pamlostracco.blogspot.com/2014/05/mountain-mural.html

Here are time lapse videos showing a different people doing similar:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iQGZi75w5LY

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QPE5G2SR0Zs

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QVQ8mPmSZS8